# How can I create a list of page titles from custom meta values?

Tags: php, theme-development, custom-field, post-meta

I want to associate pages with other pages by using custom meta values.

For one page, I want to associate two other pages, so I create a custom meta value with the key `Procedure` and the value of the other page ID, one for each page.

Then I want to display these associated pages, as their page titles, but in a comma separated list:

```
<?php echo implode(', ',get_post_meta($patient_story->ID, 'Procedure', false)); ?>
```

This is nearly there, but it only displays the page IDs (as it's giving the direct values in from the custom meta entries). I can't seem to integrate `get_the_title()` without breaking the code.

What's the best way I can have it so that it will convert:

```
Meta Key           Meta Value
Procedure    =>    238
Procedure    =>    240
```

into 'Page title 1, Page title 2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the title for each post ID in your array.  The straightforward way is this:

```
$procedure_title_list = array();
$procedure_list = get_post_meta($patient_story->ID, 'Procedure', false);
foreach ( $procedure_list as $procedure ) {
    $procedure_title_list[] = get_the_title( $procedure );
}
echo implode( ', ', $procedure_title_list );
```

Comment: Brilliant, I was thinking it must have been something simple, thanks.